# String that is being read in by stream reader is producing unrecognizable characters

Tags: c#, string, encoding

I am using a `StreamReader` To read in some `chars` into a buffer, then converting it to a `string` and splitting it on a NUL combination. This is just the way the file format is. However I get funky "?" characters in the string when I read in something from a different language (Acústicos for example has a '?' for the accent character). I have tried some of the encoding solutions, but I'm not sure how to implement it into a `StreamReader` based solution, here's what I'm doing now:

```
 using (StreamReader _sr = new StreamReader(FilePath)){
                char[] _buffer = new char[1024];
                _sr.Read(_buffer, 0, 32);

                _sr.Read(_buffer,0,200);
                string _stuff = new string(_buffer);

                string[] _test = _stuff.Split(new[] { "\0\0\0" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

                //Title
                string _name = ParseFile(_test, _k);
  }

private string ParseFile(string[] test, int k) {
        bool _flag = false;
        string _name = string.Empty;
        int _i;
        //Assign i to the k counter so that we don't always start at the beginning and get the same string
        for (_i = k; _i < test.Length; _i++) {
            for (int _j = 0; _j < test[_i].Length; _j++) {
                if (char.IsControl(test[_i][_j])) {
                }
                else {//This contains a real string. Get out and return
                    _flag = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (_flag) {
                break;
            }
        }
        if (_flag) {
            _k = _i;
            _name = test[_i].Substring(1);
        }
        return _name;
    }
```

The question is: **How can I use all these strings to get the correct character from the file?**

Comment: Can you post a sample file content, on which you are getting this problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that's caused by wrong encoding

replace

```
 using (StreamReader _sr = new StreamReader(FilePath))
```

with

```
using (StreamReader _sr = new StreamReader(FilePath, System.Text.Encoding.Default))
```

to use the current encoding of your operating system